If $χ_p$ is ramified then $χ(p) = 0$
Consider suppose that $χ_{idelic}$ is the idelic lift of the Dirichlet character $χ$. In my text, it says that if the local character $χ_p$ is ramified that is there exists some u
$\in Z_p^{x}$ such that $χ_p(u)\neq1$ then $χ(p)=0$.
Could someone explain how this is true.

It's not the local character $\chi_p$ that's $0$, it's the number $\chi(p)$, i.e., the value of your original Dirichlet character at the number $p$. In other words, the ramified places are the ones dividing the conductor of the classical character.

yes, () is 0 is what I have to show. By definition of idelic lift, $()=()−1$
given that $∈(+^),(,)=1$
. So is your answer related to this definition ? Yes i had made a typo in the problem I edited it.

There is no $j$ such that $p \in (j + p^j \mathbb{Z}_p)$ but also $(j, p) = 1$.
